# Did I kill windows boot manager? I can't boot after installing FreeBSD

Tags: boot, unix, freebsd, boot-partition, boot-manager

I installed freebsd with dual-booting. I specified an empty partition for freebsd auto-configuring.

After it was installed, windows boot manager disappeared.

What's going on? Should I recover it, or install an alternative boot manager?

by the way, what is UEFI and GPT? is that matter?

Comment: Did you install any boot manager (grub, lilo, etc)?

Comment: I tried boot0cfg, but in pain. then I tried to install grub2 from  fedora but it cannot read bsd disk.

Comment: What kind of filesystems are you using on Windows and FreeBSD? grub should be able to boot FreeBSD UFS disks (i am using Debian and Ubuntu's grub).

Comment: Work to enable FreeBSD to boot from UEFI is [ongoing](https://wiki.freebsd.org/201305DevSummit/UEFI) but not integrated into a release yet. Current FreeBSD releases cannot boot from UEFI.